# Python futures : How do I get the json from a future object in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, python-3.4, concurrent.futures, motorengine

This is a `post` handler :

**handler.py**

```
from imports import logic

@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    data = self.request.body.decode('utf-8')
    params = json.loads(data)
    model_id= params['model_id']
    logic.begin(model_id)
```

The `logic` object is imported from imports.py where it is instantiated from an imported class `Logic`

**imports.py :**

```
import Models
import Logic

class Persist(object):
    def getModel(self, model_id):
        model = Models.findByModelId(model_id)
        return model


persist = Persist()
logic = Logic(persist)
```

**logic.py**

```
class Logic(object):
    def __init__(self, persist):
        self._persist = persist

    def begin(self, model_id):
         model = self._persist.get_model(model_id)
         print ("Model from persist : ")
         print (model)
```

the `get_model` method uses `Models` which makes a DB query and returns the future object :

**model.py**:

```
from motorengine.document import Document

class Models(Document):
    name = StringField(required=True)

def findByModelId(model_id):
    return Models.objects.filter(_id=ObjectId(model_id)).find_all()
```

This prints a future object in console :

```
<tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x7fbb147047b8>
```

How can I convert it to json ?

Answer (score 4):

To resolve a `Future` into an actual value, `yield` it inside a coroutine:

```
@gen.coroutine
def begin(self, model_id):
     model = yield self._persist.get_model(model_id)
     print ("Model from persist : ")
     print (model)
```

Any function that calls a coroutine must be a coroutine, and it must `yield` the return value of the coroutine to get its return value:

```
@gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    data = self.request.body.decode('utf-8')
    params = json.loads(data)
    model_id = params['model_id']
    model = yield logic.begin(model_id)
    print(model)
```

More advanced coding patterns don't need to follow these rules, but to begin with, follow these basic rules.

For more information about calling coroutines from coroutines, see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).